# How to switch to a Displayable class that has the main method

Tags: java, java-me, lcdui

I'm working in java me, I'm trying to switch between visual designs using ok Commands and back Commands. I have a form displayable which I named `formA` in my main class `A.java` and a `formB` in another class `B.java`. I used an ok Command in `formA` which on selection, is supposed to take the user to `formB`. At first when I tried to call the `getFormB` method from my main class, it didn't work(non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context).

I was adviced to create a reference to B.java so I added this line in my main class `A.java`

```
B b = new B(this);
```

now I could call the getFormB method from my commandAction in `formA`. At this point, everything worked well but when I tried to add a backCommand which is supposed to take me back to `formA` in `A.java` I get ds error again 'non-static method `getFormA()` cannot be referenced from a static context', so I tried creating a reference in `B.java` same way I did in `A.java`, here's the code:

```
A a = new A();
```

then in command action I did ds on the backCommand:

```
switchDisplayable(null, a.getFormA());
```

This time, it compiled without errors. But at runtime I get a SecurityException MIDlet Manager ERROR:

> Illegal attempt to construct hello.A@e938beb1

'hello' is the package containing both java files.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your A class extends MIDlet. If this is the case you should not try to make a new instance of it.
You should add an A attribute to your B class and receive the instance as a constructor parameter or have a setter method.
With this you can call the getFormA() method from the attribute.
**Update**

```
public class A extends MIDlet {
  B b;

  public A() {
    b = new B(this);
  }
}

class B {
  A a;

  B(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
    switchDisplayable(null, a.getFormA());
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the A class extends MIDlet. Can I get a code sample on adding the attribute to the B class pls, and also how to use the setter method pls, so I get an idea how to implement those in code

Comment: It compiled, no errors. But I get a NullPointerException at runtime. Why does that happen and how do I fix it pls

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Just got to know about stack trace now. I got sth lyk ds 4rm the output window in my IDE, I hope I'm in line.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at B.getDisplay(B.java:137)
at B.switchDisplayable(B.java:65)
at B.commandAction(B.java:106)

Comment: Sorry I typed that from my mobile. The browser doesn't allow me to proper indent and arrange my lines. The word "at" starts every line

Comment: Did you call Display.getDisplay(a) inside switchDisplayable?